# How to insert business logic in django template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-filter

I am working on review rating form, and I want to display the rating stars given by the user. I am getting an int value rating from the database out of 5 rating.

However I want to implement a logic in django template that would looks like the follow code,

```
a = "THIS IS A STRING"
b = "THIS IS B STRING"
max_val = 5
def review_rating(val):
    flag = 0
    for i in range(max_val):
        if flag == 0:
            for j in range(val):
                print(a)
            flag = 1 
        
        new_val = max_val - val
        for k in range(new_val):
            print(b)
        break

review_rating(1)
```

Note: `val` is the rating value from database.

I have tried with filters,

Following is my filter code,

```
@register.filter(name='subtract')
def subtract(value, arg):
    return int(value) - int(arg)
```

and following is my django template code,

```
<p class="starsnd-small">
                                                                    
    {% with ''|center:review.review_star as range %}
        {% for _ in range %}
                <b value="" id="checked" href="#"></b>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}

    {% with {{5|subtract:review.review_star}} as range %}
        {% for _ in range %}
            <b value="" href="#"></b>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
                                                            
</p>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: checkout this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: please specify your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use django templatetags https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

You will need to have a folder called templatetags and as well in you html file you need to load you registered filter
{% load subtract %}

Comment: okay. and the logic that I have applied in django template do you think its worth ? please suggest.